# Periodic workspace save could not save safe table?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-rad

I'm a newbie and I'm using the IBM RAD which is based on Eclipse. After install I deleted some files that seemed not needed in C:\workspace. Now I get this error:
[image]
"Periodic workspace table can not be saved, file could not be found, could not save file table to C:\workspace.metadata..."
Could you tell what I should do to resolve the error? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restore the files you deleted.

If you have no way to do that, create a new workspace (**File** > **Switch Workspace** > **Other...**) and then import your projects from the old one into the new one.

Answer (score 4):

If you get this error in Linux environment, just update the ownership of the file below, and make the owner as same as the owner of the workspace folder:

```
<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.safetable/org.eclipse.core.resources
```

This solution works for Eclipse version 4.3

Answer (score 1):

This error message happened to me when I was copying old project files and importing (all) files to new project. I did following and solved the issue:

1. Created a new workspace, and switched current workspace to that
   one, and close Eclipse.
2. Created a missing folder, in this case, "org.eclipse.core.resources".
3. In Eclipse, switched to previous workspace, and started working with Eclipse. After a while, Eclipse created necessary files and that error message was gone.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happened beacuse you deleted .metadata folder in your workspace folder in "my documents" folder in windows.
Solution: Reinstall